# Use of Distinct keyword using in https://parse.com/

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have a `Table` named `Scheduel_Deails`,
the fields are `Schedule_Title`, `Schedule_Track` and many more

now the record content data

```
("Title 1","Track 1")
("Title 1","Track 2")
("Title 1","Track 1")
("Title 1","Track 1")
```

Now i wanna the field `Schedule_Track`

ie. `Track 1` and `Track 2` only..
Now how to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse.com is not support the distinct and aggregate queries.
In that case we must do that on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Check how many object on page are returned -> something like self.ObjectperPage =2. Or find cellForRowAtIndexPath and manipulate the cells based on desired index.

Another way is to change - (PFQuery *)queryForTable .